# Format <<<target links>>> in org-mode for printing

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel, pdf, hyperlinks

Is there a way to format target links created by org-mode when using radio targets such as the following:

```
<<<some text>>> where that some text is linked back
```

When outputting to HTML or PDF (created through LaTeX processor), the links are active and work well when clicked. However, I want the second "some text" printed in a different format so visually it's apparent that is a hyperlink. By default radio source and targets print the same.